# Create dump, backup in Postgrsql

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

I have problems with backup my postgresql database.
I was trying something like this:

```
sudo psql -U postgres
```

then I listed my databases via \l (Ok. my database it here, so I wanna backup it)

```
pg_dump db_name > /Users/myUser/Desktop/dump01.sql
```

And I got an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_dump"
```

Other thing which I tried:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump db_test ~/Desktop/dump.sql
-----------
could not identify current directory: Permission denied
pg_dump: error: too many command-line arguments (first is "/Users/user/Desktop/dump.sql")
```

I'm on MacOs Catalina (Latest version)

Comment: you have to execute the pg_dump on commandline not in psql

Comment: If I do this i got and error that I pass bad password for my user. Weird...

Comment: sudo -u postgres pg_dump ...

Comment: so.
 sudo -u postgres pg_dump database ~/Desktop/ttt.sql
pg_dump: error: too many command-line arguments (first is "/Users/user/Desktop/ttt.sql")

Comment: sudo -u postgres pg_dump database >~/Desktop/ttt.sql

Comment: Now I have permission deined od the directory
zsh: permission denied: /Users/user/Desktop/ttt.sql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218434/discussion-between-programmer-and-fatfreddy).

Comment: "If I do this i got and error that I pass bad password for my user"  Then pass it the correct password.